# Formatting of multiple quotes ends up showing as a single block

Tags: support, markdown, formatting

When I make three quotes with an answer under each quote, the editor resolves that as one quote all mushed together. The answers under the first two quotes disappear.

What is the trick to make multiple quotes with associated answers?

Answer (score 4):

Not sure what the fix is supposed to be but:

```
>Hello

<!-- This is a comment -->

>world!
```

resolves to

> Hello

> world!

For a neat break between quote blocks.

Apparently this is [also the suggested fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3358056/multiple-blockquotes-in-a-row-using-markdown-syntax) as of 2012.

It looks like any non-whitespace characters will cause the markdown formatter to trigger a break, so you can use a `<br/>` tag or even the `&nbsp;` character code in place of the `<!-- comment -->` html tag.

Comment: The alternative suggestions both add a much wider gap, so they're not equivalent. Which to use is probably personal preference.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I guess I have to really learn this editor. Gives me trouble on the HTG forum too.

Comment: Or insert a single `<i>` to divide them